# Return Number Of Records Updated

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using `C#` to run a `Sql Server` stored procedure.  My syntax is as such

```
Update [silly]
Set [validname] = case 
                  when [Name] Not In ('BBABABA', 'SDLJK', 'KJSDJK') 
                  Then 'Yes' 
                  Else 'No' 
                  end
where [validname] IS NULL
```

Which of course when executed will return `5 rows updated` or however many rows were updated.  Question being, is there a way for me to return to my `C#` syntax how many rows were updated with `Yes` and how many rows were updated with `'No'`

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: use select @@rowcount at the end of query and add outputparameter in stored procedure as well

Comment: @rashfmnb no need. [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) *already* returns that number.

Comment: If you want it broken down by `Yes` and `No` counts, then do a count of each before you do the update and send that back to your c# code.

Comment: @RashidInman how do you execute this statement? ExecuteNonQuery already returns the number of modified rows. Please post the code you used

Comment: @RickS exactly. See me my answer. There is no result set produced by the UPDATE statement that you can query to obtain what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of SQL, you could use the [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, that would return a dataset that you could count the rows

```
Update [silly]
Set [validname] = case 
                  when [Name] Not In ('BBABABA', 'SDLJK', 'KJSDJK') 
                  Then 'Yes' 
                  Else 'No' 
                  end
Output inserted.validname
where [validname] IS NULL
```

EDIT

If you are looking to avoid iterating the results in .net I think you can  output the results into a temp table and then run a query on the temp table

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
      validname [varchar] NULL
    )

Update [silly]
Set [validname] = case 
                  when [Name] Not In ('BBABABA', 'SDLJK', 'KJSDJK') 
                    Then 'Yes' 
                    Else 'No' 
                  end
Output inserted.validname into @temp
where [validname] IS NULL

SELECT validname, count(*)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY validname
```

Comment: This would return the resulting values that were updated in a dataset, in which you could count within the .net code.

Comment: Really cool stuff on the output clause! My answer just says this imaginary result set is not produced my Sql server... I thought it was not implemented good to see I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

No, SQL Server Update statement will return a single value, the number of updated columns and that it. It will not look into the condition/cases in your update statement. You need to change your SP.

You need to change your stored procedure to first count the rows with `[Name] not in ('banana', 'strawberry', 'tomatoes')` and those that do not satisfy this condition. Then you need to perform the update and return as 2 OUT parameters the counts.

Wrap in transaction if required.

PS. it would be cool if the update/insert/delete statements returned or filled a temporary table instead of just returning a number of affected records, but that is not the case (let me know if i'm wrong :D)

Comment: I could do a select that returns a count of the avaliable then run the update and compare the difference in the two counts.  But ? remains how do I return this data to my C#